# How to change Fluent UI controls default blue color when focus in react

Tags: reactjs, fluentui-react

I am using Fluent UI with react. I am trying to change default focus color in my dropdown.
below is my code. But this is not changing color.

[image]

```
const dropdownStyles = {
  Dropdown: {
    selectors: {
      ":focus": {
        borderColor: "green",
      },
    },
  },
};


<Dropdown
    placeholder="Select an option"
    label="Favorite Fruit"
    options={options}
    styles={dropdownStyles}
  />
```

[This is my sample Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-bird-rgo6of?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

You miss `:after`:

```
<Dropdown
  styles={{
    dropdown: {
      selectors: { ':focus:after': { borderColor: '#f00' } } 
    }
  }}
/>
```

Codepen working [example](https://codepen.io/savkelita/pen/yLxEQax?editors=0010).